# FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword() doesn't work with the new firebase sdk version

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I recently updated my firebase sdk version to the latest and all of a sudden the **FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()** doesn't work anymore and it shows me this error:

```
W/Binder: Binder call failed.
      com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzv: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONObject com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.zzbf()' on a null object reference
```

This is my code:

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString())
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.v("trtrrt",e.toString());
                        }
                    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                            Log.v("trtrrt","success");
                        }
            });
```

The weird thing is when i enter a wrong email and password it calls the `OnFailureListener`, but if I enter a right email and password neither `OnSuccessListener` nor `OnFailureListener` get called.

Here is my current dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.5.1'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.12.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.12.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:15.0.0'

    implementation 'com.simplify:simplify-android:3.0.0'


    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem wasn't because i didn't use

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

the sign in method was working fine before i upgraded the version of the Firebase SDK.

However, i solved the problem when i downgraded the firebase-auth dependence to:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```
mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstace();
```

before calling signinWithEmailAndPass method on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

on your btn login click call this method

```
 private void loginUser(String email, String password) {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
           if (task.isSuccessful()){

                mpProgressDialog.dismiss();
               Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
               intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
               startActivity(intent);
               finish();
           }else{
               mpProgressDialog.hide();
               Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Something error !!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
            }
        });

    }
```